# Can a web based mobile app send SMS message alerts to various cell phones?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

We have a calendar scheduling app that needs to be able to send SMS text messages to cell phones. I am not sure how to begin on this. The app is a web app made using jQuery Mobile on a Lamp Stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) for stuff like this before. The docs are [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/index) and they have a PHP library [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php).

You can setup a Twilio account, and then when your app wants to send an SMS it calls a PHP handler on your server that sends the request to Twilio. Works quite well for an equipment monitoring application I built last year.

Answer (score 2):

if you can implement a SMS gateway using LAMP stack you can implement it. Web would be just front end for it.

Answer (score 2):

I've sent text messages by way of email before. It's been a few years but last time I did it I just used these email suffix's:

```
T-Mobile: phonenumber@tmomail.net
Virgin Mobile: phonenumber@vmobl.com
Cingular: phonenumber@cingularme.com
Sprint: phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
Verizon: phonenumber@vtext.com
Nextel: phonenumber@messaging.nextel.com

where phonenumber = your 10 digit phone number
```